# How to Persist data in One to One Relationship Using JPA JSF

Tags: jsf, jpa, primefaces, one-to-one, facade

**At the First I will let u Know what i want to achieve and Later I will Show u the Problem.**

[image]

In the Above screen Title  and Description is from the AboutUs Entity and rest of the fields are for GeneralImage Entity.

Now what I want to achieve is when I click on create Button I want to persist data in two entities and have one to one relationship with each other

In order to do this I have written the below code which has the problem

**AboutUs.java**

```
package com.model;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "AboutUs.findAboutUsByIdWithImages", query = "Select s from AboutUs s where
s.aboutusid = :aboutusid")       
public class AboutUs implements Serializable
{   
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private int aboutusid;
  private String aboutustitle;
  private String description;

  public static final String FIND_ABOUTUS_BY_ID_WITH_IMAGES =   
  "AboutUs.findAboutUsByIdWithImages";
  @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "imageid")
private GeneralImage image;
//Here Below I have Added Setters and Getters
……….
}
```

**GeneralImage**

```
@Entity
public class GeneralImage {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int imageid;
private String fileName;
private String categoryid;
private int orderofappearance;
private String mimetype;
private int filesize;
private int foreignkeyid;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="image", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private AboutUs aboutus;

//The Below Are The Setters and Getters
}
```

**The below is My Facelets Image**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:body>
  <p:dialog widgetVar="aboutusCreateDialogWidget"
    id="aboutusCreateDialogId" height="400" width="1000" modal="true"
  closable="true" draggable="false" resizable="false" showEffect="puff" hideEffect="fold"
  header="Create About Us">  
    <h:form id="aboutusCreateDialogForm" prependId="false">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="* #{msgs.aboutustitle}" />
            <h:inputText value="#{aboutUsMB.aboutus.aboutustitle}" required="true" label="#
            {msgs.aboutustitle}" >
                <f:validateLength minimum="4" />
            </h:inputText>

            <h:outputText value="* #{msgs.aboutusescription}" />
            <h:inputText value="#{aboutUsMB.aboutus.description}" required="true" label="#
            {msgs.aboutusescription}" />

            <h:outputText value="* #{msgs.categoryName}" />
            <h:inputText value="#{generalImageMB.generalImage.categoryid}" required="true"   
            label="#{msgs.categoryName}" />

            <h:outputText value="* #{msgs.orderOfAppearance}" />
            <h:inputText value="#{generalImageMB.generalImage.orderofappearance}" required="true" 
            label="#{msgs.orderOfAppearance}" />

            <h:outputText value="* #{msgs.mimetype}" />
            <h:inputText value="#{generalImageMB.generalImage.mimetype}" required="true" label="#
            {msgs.mimetype}" />

            <h:outputText value="* #{msgs.fileSize}" />
            <h:inputText value="#{generalImageMB.generalImage.filesize}" required="true" label="#
            {msgs.fileSize}" />
        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:panelGrid columns = "2">
        <p:commandButton value="#{msgs.create}" icon="ui-icon-plus"
                action="#{aboutUsMB.createAboutus()}"
                update=":messageGrowl :aboutusForm:aboutusTable"
                oncomplete="closeDialogIfSucess(xhr, status, args, aboutusCreateDialogWidget,  
                'aboutusCreateDialogId')" 
                />
        <p:commandButton value="#{msgs.cancel}" icon="ui-icon-cancel" actionListener="#
        {aboutusMB.resetAboutus()}" onclick="aboutusCreateDialogWidget.hide();" type="button" />

        </h:panelGrid>
     </h:form> 
   </p:dialog>
 </h:body>
</html>
```

**Next I have AboutUsMB
AboutUsMB
In AboutUsMB  my createAboutus()**

```
public void createAboutus() 
{
try 
{   
    aboutus.setImage(generalImage);  //Here I am adding the generalImage object to about so that 
                                     //it can be persisted
    aboutusFacade.save(aboutus);
    closeDialog();
    displayInfoMessageToUser("Created With Success......!");
    loadAboutus();
    resetAboutus();
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    keepDialogOpen();
    displayErrorMessageToUser("OOPS, We Could Not Create...... Try Again Later......!");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

**Later In Façade Classes
Save Method
AboutUsFacade**

```
public interface AboutUsFacade {
 //The Below I Am Adding Methods So That I Can Deal With Addition, Deletion and Updation of Users
 public abstract void save(AboutUs aboutus);
}
```

**Façade Implimentation Class
AboutUsFacadeImp**

```
public class AboutUsFacadeImp implements AboutUsFacade 
{
@EJB
private AboutUsDAO aboutusDAO;

@Override
public void save(AboutUs aboutus) 
{
    aboutusDAO.save(aboutus);
}
}
```

**GenericDAO Class**

```
public abstract class GenericDAO<T> 
{
  private final static String UNIT_NAME = "SmartRealtorsPU";

  @PersistenceContext(unitName = UNIT_NAME)
  private EntityManager em;
  private Class<T> entityClass;

  public GenericDAO(Class<T> entityClass) 
  {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
  }

  public void save(T entity) {
  em.persist(entity);
 }
}
```

**So After Using the above Code I am not able to have generalImage data persisted only aboutus data has been persisted also u can see that the imageid which is the field of relationship is NULL**

[image]

**So cud any One rectify that What might be the Problem and also where i am wrong and what needs to be done**

**Is i am using one form to persist is causing the Problem**

Comment: I am not understanding why it has been voted as there is no research i am trying this example from last two days and have done lot of Research On this... Is there some one who can answer the Question

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, you are mapping the bidirectional mapping on only one side.

In your AboutUsMB createAboutus() try to do the following:

Instead of

```
aboutus.setImage(generalImage);
```

do

```
aboutus.setImage(generalImage);
generalImage.setAboutus(aboutus);
```